# Should a Javascript function avoid reject a promise via a ternary condition?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I saw a piece of code that looks funny to me. It feels like there are multiple things wrong here. Am I seeing a ternary here returning an error rather than a value?  Shouldn't this therefore be an `if`-`else`?

```
const aData = await response.json();
return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  (aData.title === aName)
    ? resolve('A data was found')
    : reject(new Error('Incorrect data was returned'));
});
```

Comment: You are not returning anything. Also, per my opinion, its always better to have a `if` condition as it is more readable. However, its my POV

Comment: There is no throwing an error, it is just someone trying to write less code by using a ternary operator. Personal opinion if it is good or bad, you will find people say it is fine and others will say it is horrible.

Comment: I'm guilty of using ternary operators for returns

`return this.value ? this.value : this.defaultValue;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `resolve` and `reject` just return the value `undefined`, and your callback function doesn't `return` anything at all. Using a ternary operator to make it a single expression is rather useless.
For clarity, you should better write

```
if (aData.title === aName) resolve('A data was found');
else reject(new Error('Incorrect data was returned'));
```

although really you shouldn't be using the `new Promise` constructor here at all. Just

```
const aData = await response.json();
if (aData.title !== aName) throw new Error('Incorrect data was returned');
else return 'A data was found';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Gives me 2 additional things to think about.   I know this must be an unusual pattern  (and therefore not opinionated) since I tried Googling and couldn't  find anyone else doing it.